# How can I get field's value of entry in other site locale in my element-api endpoint?

Tags: craft3, plugin-elementapi

I'd like to get a field value in 3 differents locales in the same element-api endpoint but I can't make a request similar to this one :  craft.entries.siteId($siteId).id($entryId).one() in twig.

```
<?php

use Craft;
use craft\elements\Entry;

return [
  'endpoints' => [
    'exhibitions.json' => function() {
      return [
        'elementType' => Entry::class,
        'criteria' => [
          'section' => 'exhibitions',
          // 'locale' => ['francais','english', 'deutsch']
        ],
        'transformer' => function(Entry $entry) {

          // -- Description --
          $description_fr = ($entry->summary) ? $entry->summary : ($entry->body) ? $entry->body : '';
          // $entry_en = $craft->entries->siteId(2).id($entry->id).one();
          // $description_en = ($entry_en->summary) ? $entry_en->summary : ($entry_en->body) ? $entry_en->body : '';
          // $entry_de = $craft->entries->siteId(3).id($entry->id).one();
          // $description_de = ($entry_de->summary) ? $entry_de->summary : ($entry_de->body) ? $entry_de->body : '';

          // -- Tags --
          $tags = '['.$entry->exhibitionsType->label.']';
          foreach ($entry->exhibitionsCats as $key => $cat) {
            $tags .= ',['.$cat['title'].']';
          }

          return [
            'type' => [
              array('target_id' => 'event')
            ],
            'title' => [
              array('value' => $entry->title)
            ],
            'field_subtitle' => [
              array('value' => $entry->subtitle)
            ],
            'field_description_fr' => [
              array('value' => $description_fr)
            ],
            // 'field_description_en' => [
            //   array('value' => $description_en)
            // ],
            // 'field_description_de' => [
            //   array('value' => $description_de)
            // ],
            'pictures' => [
              'url' => $entry->banner->one()->url,
              'copy' => $entry->banner->one()->legend,
              'alt' => $entry->banner->one()->legend
            ],
            'field_event_type' => [
              array('value' => '3') // Long or permanent event (3)
            ],
            'field_date' => [
              array(
                'value '=> $entry->fromDate->format('Y-m-dTH:i:s'),
                'end_value '=> $entry->toDate->format('Y-m-dTH:i:s'),
                'rrule '=> null,
              )
            ],
            'field_state' => [
              array('value' => 'scheduled')
            ],
            'field_type' => [
              array('target_id' => 6) // Audience - Pour tout public (6)
            ],
            'field_categories' => [
              array('target_id' => 24347) // Exhibitions (24347)
            ],
            'field_tags_rest' => [
              array('value' => $tags)
            ],
            'field_location' => [
              array('target_id' => 5179)
            ],
            'field_websites' => [
              array(
                'uri' => $entry->url,
                'title' => $entry->title)
            ],
            'field_email_address' => [
              array('value' => getenv('EIL_EMAIL'),)
            ],
          ];
        },
      ];
    }
  ]
];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay I found a way to do it if it can help someone:

```
$description_fr = ($entry->summary) ? $entry->summary : ($entry->body) ? $entry->body : '';
$entry_en = Entry::find()->id($entry->id)->siteId(2)->one();
$description_en = ($entry_en['summary']) ? $entry_en['summary'] : ($entry_en['body']) ? $entry_en['body'] : '';
$entry_de = Entry::find()->id($entry->id)->siteId(3)->one();
$description_de = ($entry_de['summary']) ? $entry_de['summary'] : ($entry_de['body']) ? $entry_de['body'] : '';
```